# Collection view cells duplicate when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, textview, uicollectionview

I've got a collection view and I've got a custom class for the cells. Each cell contains a text view, here is the code:

```
class CustomWriterPageCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

    fileprivate let textViewOne: UITextView = {

        let tv = UITextView()
        tv.backgroundColor = .cyan
        tv.text = "Chapter Title"
        tv.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Roman", size: 27)
        tv.textColor = .gray
        return tv

    }()
}
```

Here is the `cellForItemAt`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "WriterPageCellID", for: indexPath) as! CustomWriterPageCell
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear

    return cell
}
```

The text view has a placeholder that I've achieved through the following code (This is inside the custom cell class):

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    if textView.textColor == .gray {

        textView.text = nil
        textView.textColor = .black
    }
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    if textView.text.isEmpty {
        textView.textColor = .gray
        textView.text = "Chapter Title"
    }
}
```

The problem is that, whatever I type on the text view of the first cell, appears on the 4th cell, I know that this is happening because of `dequeueReusableCell` but I can't seem to solve this problem.

Comment: Simple solution, whenever you use `if` , make sure to also write `else` with opposite logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't specify what text to appear on each of your CollectionViewCell's textView. As long as you don't specify the same in `cellForItemAt indexPath` it is going to show the reused cell and its content, from `dequeueReusableCell` as you said.

For the solution to your specific problem you can do as below in the viewcontroller:

```
`var textViewContentArray = [Int: String]()` //Create a dictionary to hold the texts globally
```

In ***textViewDidEndEditing***:

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.isEmpty {
        textView.textColor = .gray
        textView.text = "Chapter Title"
    } else {
        guard let cell = textView.superview?.superview as? CustomWriterPageCell else {
            return
        }
        guard  let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
        textViewContentArray[indexPath.row] = textView.text
    }
}
```

In ***textViewDidBeginEditing***:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.textColor = .black
}
```

And in ***cellForItemAt indexPath***:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomWriterPageCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomWriterPageCell
    cell.textView.delegate = self
    let text = textViewContentArray[indexPath.row]
    if !text.isEmpty {
        cell.textView.textColor = .black
        cell.textView.text = text
    } else {
        cell.textView.textColor = .gray
        cell.textView.text = "Chapter Title"
    }
    return cell
}
```

**Note**: Here I am assuming you have set the Controller which holds the collectionView as delegate for the textViewInCell, if the cell is the delegate you can update the textViewContentArray using protocol

Hope this adds to your understanding.

Comment: Hey, I kinda works but the text color is gray and I can't seem to solve that problem :/

Comment: I mean when I scroll (go to the 4th cell) and when I come back (to the first cell) the text color is gray

Comment: Hey umm so new problem, I’ve got a placeholder text ryt and once you type on the text view, the text color changes to black, since this happens when this cell gets reused the text color is black In the other cell get it?

Comment: Hey, 'if let text = text' gives this error "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'"

Comment: `let text = textViewContentArray[indexPath.row]` this doesn’t return an optional string

Comment: @SMALLworld See the edit in the answer, changed the conditional binding.

Comment: Okay so now when you empty the text view, and scroll to the other cells and come back, the text color is black

Comment: Hey, fixed it, hope I dont get any bugs later, Thanks man. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that 4th cell does not fit in current view (i.e available below on scroll - i.e Reused cell)

1) If you are reusing cell then you need to ensure that before cell goes out of view you need to save `UITextView` data somewhere. Otherwise it will lose data (i.e text written) due to reuse. Save data for each cell in data structure/any form.

2) If you scroll to 4th cell then check if data exists. If does not then set empty state to text view. If you write something then save data for 4th cell in data structure/any form..
(You can use this `textViewDidEndEditing()` to save current data)

3) Again scroll back to 1st cell type something there are save data of 1st cell data structure/any form for that index.

4) Now scroll back to 4th cell. During reuse set saved data of 4th cell to cell text view.

`Data Saved at Index == Cell Index`

Make sure you handle your use case correctly. There is nothing wrong with the reuse implementation. Make sure you save data and reset data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the part you want to change is encapsulated into a model, such as the `textColor`, `text` you mentioned. Don't manually change the UI display, I mean by modifying the model and then refreshing the UI, so that's not There will be repetitions.

This is the rule for all tables, modify the model to refresh the UI, I hope to be useful to you.